# Can I specify what type of URLs to search for? - Google Search

Tags: google-api, google-ajax-api

Ok I'm searching for twitter profiles with **Google Ajax Search**

I'm using the following **query**:

```
?q=Radiant+Hex+site:twitter.com
```

**I'm looking for urls like these:**

```
twitter.com/radianthex
twitter.com/ignighted
...
```

**But I often stumble in URLs of the form:**

```
twitter.com/lindsaylohan/status/7537167235
twitter.com/calvinharris/status/1905934068
```

Is there a way of removing these url from my search?

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=horse+site%3Atwitter.com+-inurl%3Astatuses+-inurl%3Astatus
```

the query being:

```
horse site:twitter.com -inurl:statuses -inurl:status
```

specifically it looks like you can use negation on the `inurl` keyword

Answer (score 1):

yeah if using the negate option in google, you could do that to get rid of some more sub-paths:

```
site:twitter.com (inurl:radianthex OR inurl:ignighted OR inurl:billgates)
-inurl:status -inurl:statuses -inurl:favorites -inurl:lists
```

is it possible to use the twitter api directly? they have a nice method to search for users...

the twitter call would look like this:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.xml?q=radianthex
```

theyll give you a password when you signup for free access...

they have some cool search options to tighten the results to make them more relevant for your app

Comment: I didn't know you could do it with twitter API. But how will the results compare to Google's?

Comment: Thanks jspcal I tried it... but the results have no ordering and it's hard to know which users are the actual users I'm looking for.
Google offers a better search by relevance.

Comment: thanks jspcal, you have been very clear. I guess one way I could narrow my search is by using the number or followers.
Btw did you put Bill there because he got his profile verified today?

Comment: "Both the Streaming API and the Search API filter out all statuses from low-quality users. Unlike Search, Streaming does not filter or rank statuses for relevance, all statuses are available." From Twitter API's Wiki

Comment: hmm very interesting, yeah i noticed billg just got verified, so a good way to test the freshness :)